# How do I get text to rotate correctly?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I can never seem to get text to rotate correctly inside a plot, whereas the same text rotates perfectly otherwise. For example,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> 
  First@Graphics[Rotate[Text["Sine", {Pi, 1/2}], -30 Degree]]]
```

gives the following.

[image]

The text is skewed and hardly legible. How do I rotate the text correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The skewing happens because the text is directly included and the scale of the two axis is not the same. If you set `AspectRatio` to `Automatic` the scale will be the same and the text is readable:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> First@Graphics[Rotate[Text["Sine", {Pi, 1/2}], -30 Degree]],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To keep the aspect ratio (which is probably what you want), wrap the text in `Inset`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> Inset[Rotate[Text["Sine"], -70 Degree], {Pi, 1/2}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

You can also move the `Rotate` inside the `Text`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Text[Rotate["Sine", -70 Degree], {Pi, 1/2}]]
```

which will also avoid the skewing from the aspect ratio.
[image: rotated text]